# Importing a downloaded .obj file to blender, how do I add textures that are provided in .png format?

Tags: animation, blender

So, as a starter on Blender, I've downloaded a 3d file from the internet. I've been able to import the object (.obj file) to the scene, but noticed one thing: There are 12 pictures in a folder called "Textures" that come with the downloaded object. How do I import these textures to the scene and apply them to the object? It is a good note that the object itself is not a whole, it is a combination of other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender objects use materials to add color and shading to each mesh face. We assign textures to each material. The UV map image textures are assigned to a material in a process called skinning. You might just need to select the object and then look in the Material and Texture properties. Each Texture will have a folder icon to set the location of the texture image file.

YouTube offers many how-to videos about how to UV wrap an object. Just don't make your task too difficult. You probably only need to set the correct image texture png for each UV texture.

Hang in there and good luck.